# setReorderingAllowed() and backStackChangedListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(() -> {
        Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_LOG_TAG,"BackStackChangedListener");
});
Fragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).setReorderingAllowed(true).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).addToBackStack(null).setReorderingAllowed(true).commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_LOG_TAG,Integer.toString(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()));
```

This is my logcat:

```
2022-08-08 12:45:02.419 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: onCreate(Bundle)
2022-08-08 12:45:02.652 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/crime_fragment_log_tag: onAttach(Context)
2022-08-08 12:45:02.653 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/crime_fragment_log_tag: onAttach(Activity)
2022-08-08 12:45:02.653 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/crime_fragment_log_tag: onCreate(Bundle)
2022-08-08 12:45:02.655 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: BackStackChangedListener
2022-08-08 12:45:02.655 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: 2
2022-08-08 12:45:02.661 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: onStart()
2022-08-08 12:45:02.664 6756-6756/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: onResume()
```

**Why does `backStackChangedListener` fire only once. It must fire whenever we change the back stack. So as you can see the back stack has been changed at least 2 times, but this listener is called 1 time. Why ?**

Comment: not quite sure but `commit()` is an scheduled operation . can u try by adding after `add` also ? first add then `fm.executePendingTransactions();` and then remove then again `fm.executePendingTransactions();` .. I think that should change back stack twice ..

Comment: @ADM okey, it works. But anyway i would like to know why my example works that way. It must work like your one, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Check source code of `executePendingTransactions()` . keep an eye on flag `mReorderingAllowed` for that transaction .. you will get a better idea ..

Comment: it's so hard to research this method to me. Is it possible that this error in code ? Because this is unexpectable behavior and i don't think it should be like this. What if someone uses this listener and this method together and the listener will fires less that it should ? I think detecting this error in some big app is going to be a very hard task. @ADM

Comment: Check [setreorderingallowed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setreorderingallowed)